# How do I make a snapshot without the navigation bar in iOS with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, snapshot

I'm using this function I've found in this site but it saves the whole screen with the navigation bar but no the status bar.

```
func screenShotMethod() {


    let layer = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow!.layer
    let scale = UIScreen.mainScreen().scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(layer.frame.size, false, scale);

    layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil)

    let alertSaved = UIAlertController(title: "Saved", message: "", preferredStyle: .ActionSheet)

    alertSaved.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: {action in

        self.view.removeGestureRecognizer(self.gesture)

    }))

    presentViewController(alertSaved, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

What I need is just take a snapshot from the end of the navigation bar to the bottom.

Comment: did you try adjusting layer.frame to exclude the status bar?

Comment: @datayeah I want to exclude the navigation bar and the status bar. How could I do what you say?

Comment: Think about it, you're taking the layer from the keyWindow which includes everything on screen. Maybe try using a different layer i.e. a view controller's view's layer

Comment: @Ian Yes! that's the problem I'm having but I don't know how to get the viewController layer. Maybe view.layer.frame.height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the layer you are attempting to screenshot from the keyWindow's view to your view controller's view, the navigation bar (assuming you have your view controller embedded in a navigation controller rather than adding a nav bar as a subview of your view) and the status bar will be omitted from the screenshot.

```
let layer = view.layer
```

If you have blank space at the top where the navigation bar was, you can adjust the frame to cut this out.

Comment: I have a top blank space just like you said. How could I adjust the frame to cut it out?

Comment: Take the layer's frame and subtract the nav bar's height from it and offset the layer's origin by the nav bar's height as well