# How to add UIView in UIImageView in ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, layer

I want to **add UIView** (UIView had contain some images and text) in **UIImageView** and that imageview i want to save in **my Camera Roll** . so please give me some suggestion or snapcode that help me to solve this problem.  [Click Here For UIScreen](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/lfbvgq92ae3b5mm/AADNWPNOtfEXExzaIuLJ-popa?dl=0)

In my case i have one `UIView` and One `UIImageView` sticker add in the UIView and I want to merge them and ya i want image in landscape mode

**Any help or suggestion can be appreciate.**

Thank You.

Comment: check this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696307/how-to-convert-a-uiview-to-a-image

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task and used this code:

```
func getResultImage() throws -> (image: UIImage, path: URL) {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(bounds.size, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    defer {
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    }
    drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    guard let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() else {
        throw ImageEditorViewError.noImageGenerated
    }

    guard let data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) else {
        throw ImageEditorViewError.noDataRepresentation
    }

    let writePath = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("Image.png")

    try data.write(to: writePath)

    return (image, writePath)
}
```

You can remove part with writePaht, as it was specific for my task

Assume, that this code is inside your container-view and you have some views-stickers inside it

Comment: Thank You for your answer but i m working on objective c not swift . its not solve my problem