# converting Image to pdf but not save in files

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uidocumentpickerviewcontroller

Hello i am opening pdf from file to imageview and then on image view i am dropping pin and after that i want to save again as pdf but its not saved in files on iphone

i also tried below solution

**https://stackoverflow.com/a/45001576/10804348**

Here Is My Code

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

class PreviewViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet private weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var image: UIImage?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let longP = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(longPressed(sender:)))
        self.imageView.addGestureRecognizer(longP)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        imageView.image = image
    }
    @objc func longPressed(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        print("longpressed")
        let touchPoint = sender.location(in: self.imageView)
        let xPOint = touchPoint.x
        let yPoint = touchPoint.y
        let buble = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: xPOint, y: yPoint, width: 20, height: 20))
        buble.image = UIImage(named: "Pin")
        imageView.addSubview(buble)
    }
    func createPDF(image: UIImage) -> NSData? {

        let pdfData = NSMutableData()
        let pdfConsumer = CGDataConsumer(data: pdfData as CFMutableData)!

        var mediaBox = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)

        let pdfContext = CGContext(consumer: pdfConsumer, mediaBox: &mediaBox, nil)!

        pdfContext.beginPage(mediaBox: &mediaBox)
        pdfContext.draw(image.cgImage!, in: mediaBox)
        pdfContext.endPage()

        return pdfData
    }
    @IBAction func btnSaveTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let docURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("myFileName.pdf")

         createPDF(image: image!)?.write(to: docURL, atomically: true)
        print("Saved")
    }
}
```

but still i am not able to save as pdf in device files, here i am attaching screen shot So You can understand easily [image: Here Is my OutPut and now i want to save as pdf with this pin]

So pelase tell me this is the right way or where i am done wrong please tell me

Comment: try creating pdf from `UIImageView` - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54730509/2955078

Comment: @Akhilrajtr Yes But how i merge both images one pdf and second is pin and then i want to save

Comment: since you are creating from `UIImageView`, it will include the subviews also in pdf. try the above solution once and share the findings

Comment: Okay i will try and tell you work or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code to save pdf file successfully at `FileManager`.

```
@IBAction func btnSaveTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
let fileManager = FileManager.default
    do {
        let documentDirectory = try fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor:nil, create:false)
        let docURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("myFileName.pdf")
        let myImage = UIImage(named: "Screen1")
        print(docURL)
        createPDF(image: myImage!)?.write(to: docURL, atomically: true)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

See Saved file in your file manager

[image]

Follow this step to show file at the path (when run with simulator)

Output path print like

> file:///Users/atulparmar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D8012A46-71C3-4A99-8D81-31890208EF03/data/Containers/Data/Application/506B9D5A-9FB0-4865-8F14-D2DB27495B05/Documents/myFileName.pdf

open Finder -> Go -> Go to Folder.. past path like following (shortcut ⇧⌘G)

> ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D8012A46-71C3-4A99-8D81-31890208EF03/data/Containers/Data/Application/506B9D5A-9FB0-4865-8F14-D2DB27495B05/Documents/myFileName.pdf

If you are run with the real device then you can check with code, see this post to check file exist or not in device [How to check if a file exists in the Documents directory in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181699/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-the-documents-directory-in-swift)

Comment: `file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/63195BAC-BEA9-41AF-9260-CABCB30D6BE4/Documents/myFileName.pdf` i am getting this path

Comment: But not able to understand where i get all this paths folder

Comment: i check in documents but nothing there with this filename

Comment: You can not check with a mobile path, run the application in a simulator and then goto specified path.

Comment: Ok but i am run on the real device and check on files on device but not save on real device

Comment: see this post , and apply code to check file is exist or not in device https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24181699/how-to-check-if-a-file-exists-in-the-documents-directory-in-swift

Comment: but first check with simulator, is it working fine with you?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188868/discussion-between-atulparmar-and-vishal-parmar).

Comment: Okay i will check and tell you till then thank you for helping

Comment: Hello @Atul Parmar i check with code file is available but not able to find on device even i search but can't find

Comment: Please tell me where exact i can find pdf file on device

Answer (score 0):

To get the context of the imageView at the moment the save button is tapped, you can update your create pdf function to render the imageview layer into a pdf context when the button is tapped. The resulting pdf contains the image plus the pins you have added:

```
func createPDF() -> NSData? {
   let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, imageView.bounds, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
    let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    imageView.layer.render(in: pdfContext!)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    return pdfData
}
```