# How to render any UIView into a UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage

How to render any UIView into a UIImage with Swift in iOS

Comment: Welcome to SO, we're here to _help_ not as a code writing service. What have you tried already? What issues are you facing with your current code?

Comment: See https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/media/how-to-render-a-uiview-to-a-uiimage to learn how to capture the screen or part of it

Comment: Thanks for your link .It's right .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code presented below can render any `UIView` into a `UIImage`:

```
let view = UIView()
let imageRenderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: view.bounds.size)
let renderedImage = imageRenderer.image {ctx in
    view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
}
```

---

The second part of the task, sharing an image to a social platform, should be posted as a separate question.

Comment: It's right .Thanks for give directions ."UIGraphicsImageRenderer' is only available on iOS 10.0 or newer"   But how can user it on iOS  9.

Comment: @Sun https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696307/how-to-convert-a-uiview-to-an-image iOS9 solution