# Transform UIView to UIImage and set it with UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift

I refered to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696307/how-to-convert-a-uiview-to-an-image) question, and did add extension to UIView:

```
extension UIView {

  // Using a function since `var image` might conflict with an existing variable
  // (like on `UIImageView`)
  func asImage() -> UIImage {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
      let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
      return renderer.image { rendererContext in
        layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
      }
    } else {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size)
      self.layer.render(in:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
      let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
      return UIImage(cgImage: image!.cgImage!)
    }
  }
}
```

Then i create very simple test view:

```
private class FakeTestView: BaseView {

  override func prepare() {
    backgroundColor = .blue
    setup()
  }

  private func setup(){
    let lbl = LabelSL.regular()
    lbl.text = "LabelSL.regular()"
    addSubview(lbl)
    lbl.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    lbl.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor).isActive = true
  }
}
```

That view showing correctly when treated as UIView.
Finally, i tried:

```
let newSlideFrame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(i) * event.expectedWidth(),
                                 y: 0,
                                 width: event.expectedWidth(),
                                 height: frame.size.height)
      let imgView = UIImageView()
      imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
      imgView.frame = newSlideFrame
      imgView.image = FakeTestView().asImage()
      scroll.addSubview(imgView)
```

But there is nothing showing. Code from above work when i try to add `UIView`, or `UIImageView` with sample images.

Comment: From your `FakeTestView` class, it looks like this view is not given a height or width. Did you make sure the height and width of the view you wish to convert to an image are not zero? If both height and width are zero your image will not show.

Comment: `imgView.image = FakeTestView().asImage()` where is your call to `prepare()` for created `FakeTestView` object ?

Comment: @RatulSharker it called right after any of init() methods (implementation is on super class).

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban Please set frame for FakeTestView init. Like : FakeTestView(frame: newSlideFrame).asImage()

Comment: @VirajPatel i tried but still no effect..