# SwiftUI: Convert entire content of Form to UIImage

Tags: ios, iphone, swiftui, swiftui-form

Not able to get SwiftUI Form content size. I am trying to get full size of a SwiftUI Form which has more content than screen size, that makes it scrollable. Using GeometryReader only gives the screen size (device height) rather than full content height. My next milestone would be to take a snapshot of the entire Form and convert it to UIImage or PDF.

Comment: You need to create an image, recontructing the form, for youself.

Comment: I didn't get you, in simple words I have scrollable Form build from SwiftUI Form component and I want to take the snapshot of the entire content both on screen, off screen

Comment: Okay...  I know what I have read.  And?

Comment: And? -> please elaborate your comment/ solution ..

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59131976/render-swiftui-view-as-an-uiimage

Comment: Thank you, but that solution didn't work, already gone through the same