# Capture part of rendered SwiftUI view as image

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have work code like this, it let user pic image from gallery and drag in specific rectangle, the one problem, is save the green frame with picked and moved picture. I have function for screenshot, but I cant make it capture correct. It capture only frame without picked picture. It would be great, if some one can help me with figured this out

[image: Image with green frame which I wont save]
[image: Image which I have]

```
import SwiftUI

struct picSelectorFrame:View {
    
    @State var isShowingImagePicker = false
    @State var      imageInBlackBox            = UIImage()
    @State var        imageSelected            = false
    @State var          imageZIndex            = 0.0
    @State private var currentPosition: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var     newPosition: CGSize = .zero
    
    var body: some View{
       let picSelector = ZStack{
             Image(uiImage: imageInBlackBox)
                 .resizable()
                 .scaledToFill()
                 .background(
                     Color.gray
                         .opacity(0.1)
                 )
                 .layoutPriority(10)
                 .zIndex(imageZIndex)
                 .gesture(DragGesture(minimumDistance: 5)
                             .onChanged({value in
                                 self.currentPosition = CGSize(width: value.translation.width + self.newPosition.width,
                                                               height: value.translation.height + self.newPosition.height)
                             })
                             .onEnded({ value in
                                 self.newPosition = self.currentPosition
                             }))
                 .offset(self.currentPosition)
             Button(action: {
                 if self.imageSelected == false {
                     self.isShowingImagePicker.toggle()
                     self.imageZIndex = 1
                     self.imageSelected = true
                 }
             }, label: {
                 Rectangle()
                     .opacity(0.1)
             }
             )
             .layoutPriority(12)
             .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingImagePicker , content: {
                 ImagePickerViewScreen(isPresented: self.$isShowingImagePicker,
                                       selectedImage: self.$imageInBlackBox)
             }
             
             )
         }
        
        ZStack{
         Rectangle()
             .fill( Color(.green))
             .opacity(0.3)
             .frame(width: 350, height: 350)
            picSelector
             .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
             .mask(
                 Rectangle()
             )
             .contentShape(
                 Rectangle()
             )
        }
        
    }
}
struct SwiftUIPhotoSelectorScreen: View {
let screenW = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    let screenH = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
    var body: some View{
        ZStack{
                picSelectorFrame()
                Button("Save"){
                takeScreenshot(origin: CGPoint(x: screenW/2-175, y: screenH/2-175),size:CGSize(width: 350, height: 350))
                }
                .position(x: screenW/2, y: screenH-50)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct ImagePickerViewScreen: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage
    
    func makeUIViewController(context:
                                UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerViewScreen>) ->
    UIViewController {
        let controller = UIImagePickerController()
        controller.delegate = context.coordinator
        return controller
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> ImagePickerViewScreen.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,
                       UINavigationControllerDelegate {
        
        let parent: ImagePickerViewScreen
        init(parent: ImagePickerViewScreen) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info:
                                    [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
            if let selectedImageFromPicker = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                self.parent.selectedImage = selectedImageFromPicker
            }
            self.parent.isPresented = false
        }
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController:
                                    ImagePickerViewScreen.UIViewControllerType, context:
                                        UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePickerViewScreen>) {
    }
}

extension View {
  func takeScreenshot(origin: CGPoint, size: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    let window = UIWindow(frame: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))
    let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: picSelectorFrame())
    window.rootViewController = hosting
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        let img = hosting.view.getImage()
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil ,nil, nil)
    return img
  }
}

extension UIView {
    func getImage() -> UIImage {
        let format = UIGraphicsImageRendererFormat()
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: self.bounds.size, format: format)
        let image = renderer.image { rendererContext in
            self.layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
        return image
    }
}

struct SwiftUIPhotoSelectorScreen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIPhotoSelectorScreen()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333377/12299030?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a View (not UIView) to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57200521/how-to-convert-a-view-not-uiview-to-an-image)

Comment: should you done it 100%  with screenshot? because there is other method as well

Comment: Did you try using existing view when capturing instead of creating new one? Maybe replace ` let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: picSelectorFrame())` with ` let hosting = UIHostingController(rootView: self)`. It seems that when you create a new view hierarchy, the image might be not picked there.

Comment: @Asperi Its first way that I try but it gave me only blank rectangles without image

Comment: @pawello2222 I tried this way too, but unfortunately, it gave me only blank rectangles as above

Comment: @Omid it doesn't have to be exactly the screenshot method. The only reason is that the user moves the picture, which makes it difficult to build the view programmatically

Comment: @Denis Yes, this is exactly the way I'm looking but replacing to rootView: self, still give me just rectangles without picture.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar problem - I get an image from the Photo library and then try to render it using view.layer.render(in: context), however, no image appears in the output.

I fixed my issue by making sure the image that comes from the UIImagePickerController is represented in 32 bits per pixel format (8 bits per component):

```
    func normalizeImage(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage? {    
        guard let cgImage = image.cgImage else {
            return nil
        }

        let width = cgImage.width
        let height = cgImage.height
        let data = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>.allocate(capacity: width * height)
        defer {
            data.deallocate()
        }
        var bitmapInfo: UInt32 = CGBitmapInfo.byteOrder32Big.rawValue
        bitmapInfo |= CGImageAlphaInfo.premultipliedLast.rawValue & CGBitmapInfo.alphaInfoMask.rawValue
            
        guard let context = CGContext(
            data: data,
            width: width,
            height: height,
            bitsPerComponent: 8,
            bytesPerRow: width * 4,
            space: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(),
            bitmapInfo: bitmapInfo
        ) else {
            return nil
        }
        context.draw(cgImage, in: .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: width, height: height)))

        guard let output = context.makeImage() else {
            return nil
        }
        return UIImage(cgImage: output)
    }
```

I would call that function in the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate to process the incoming .originalImage.