# Can you create a bitmap from a Shape/Path in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, bitmap

Is there a way of taking `Path` or `Shape` and convert them to bitmaps?

I would like to take a series of `Path` drawn by a user and a `Shape` that I drew and compare the two.

Thank you in advance for any help.

edit: adding reference page for algorithm comparing two characters https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/196788/confirming-whether-a-user-has-drawn-a-character-correctly/196797#196797

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57200521/how-to-convert-a-view-not-uiview-to-an-image. Since Path/Shape are also conforms to View, I think it should work

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the reference @SamB, I'll take a look. I also just added a link to my other post in gamdev for more context