# What is a window in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui

The closest documentation I could find was about `WindowGroup`. I came across this when I was looking at how to convert a [View into a bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57200521/how-to-convert-a-view-not-uiview-to-an-image).

The documentation on what is being represented here `UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController.view` is pretty scarce which I believe is because they weren't expecting people to access it. Could someone give me a breakdown of what windows are? How is it different from views?

Comment: Imagine windows on a pc or a Mac. On iPads and Mac devices you can have multiple windows like you have two safari windows, two Xcode windows. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/windowgroup . Windows contain Views such as buttons, menus, lists, images, etc.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheViewControllerHierarchy.html

Comment: Amazing, thank you

Comment: I'm glad it helped. I posted an answer please accept and upvote if you would like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about a PC or a Mac

> A window consists of a frame area and body area that lets the user view and interact with content in an app. A window can appear onscreen alongside other windows, or it can fill the entire screen.

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/windows-and-views/window-anatomy/

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/windowgroup

Imagine 2 Safari windows or 2 Xcode windows.

A Window contains Views such as buttons, menus, lists, images, etc.

```
 UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController.view
```

Is UIKit based code not SwiftUI, you won't find any documentation on it with the SwiftUI Framework documentation but there are plenty of "old" references that break down what it is.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/TheViewControllerHierarchy.html