# Accessing UIView after converting to image is returning a blank image

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm currently attempting to convert a `View` into an `Image` following [How to convert a UIView to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696307/how-to-convert-a-uiview-to-an-image).

I essentially want to take a drawn `Shape` either by the user or pre-made and convert it to a `UIView` then an `Image`. These `Shape` are stacked on top of one another in a `ZStack`. Something like

```swift
ZStack {

  if ... { View1( Shape1() ) }
  else if ... { View2( Shape2().backgroundRectGetter(rect: rect2) }
}
.background(RectGetter(rect: rect1))
```

I currently convert the `Shape` to a `UIView` by using `UIHostingController`.

`UIHostingController(rootView: DrawMyShape()).view` but when I convert this to an `Image` with the extension method linked I get a blank image which I assume means I'm not capturing the right view. When I use it with the `rootViewController` provided in `UIApplication` it gives the image of the entire content view.

Any insight onto why this could be happening to help debug? Thank you.

edit: adding link for `RectGetter` being used with background. [How to convert a View (not UIView) to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57200521/how-to-convert-a-view-not-uiview-to-an-image)

edit2: adding code

```swift
let image1 = UIApplication.shared.windows[0].rootViewController?.view.asImage(rect: self.rect1)

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image1, nil, nil, nil) // this writes the content view photo

// this writes a blank image
let image 2 = UIHostingController(rootView: Shape2()).view.asImage(rect: self.rect2)

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image2, nil, nil, nil)


// RectGetter in other post
struct RectGetter: View {
    @Binding var rect: CGRect
        
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { proxy in
            self.createView(proxy: proxy)
        }
    }

    func createView(proxy: GeometryProxy) -> some View {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.rect = proxy.frame(in: .global)
        }
        return Rectangle().fill(Color.clear)
    }
}
```

Comment: You had me thinking this was `UIKit` with your title - there isn't any such class called `UIView` in `SwiftUI`. Now, you *could* expose a `UIImage` (plus it's `UIImageView`) into SwiftUI and probably send to it an `Image`, but that's not what you're asking, right? Please, give us some details, some code!

Comment: @dfd apologies! I'm still very new to iOS. I added code, please let me know if that still is not clear

Comment: This can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/59333377/12299030