# How to save image with positioned signature in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, overlay

I'm working on an iOS app in SwiftUI, and I'm trying to implement a feature where the user can add their signature to an image and save the result. Currently, I have a SignatureAddingView that allows the user to add a signature overlay to an image and manipulate it (scale, rotate, and drag). However, I'm struggling to figure out how to save the image with the added signature overlay.

EDIT: The Benzy Neez's solution is working, but I can't make it work with `fixOffsetAndScale`. It's a function that monitoring the position of the image and giving the ability to zoom into it:

```
private func fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: GeometryProxy) {
        let newScale: CGFloat = .minimum(.maximum(scale, 1), 4)
        let screenSize = geometry.size
        
        let originalScale = scannedImage.size.width / scannedImage.size.height >= screenSize.width / screenSize.height ?
        geometry.size.width / scannedImage.size.width :
        geometry.size.height / scannedImage.size.height
        
        let imageWidth = (scannedImage.size.width * originalScale) * newScale
        
        var width: CGFloat = .zero
        if imageWidth > screenSize.width {
            let widthLimit: CGFloat = imageWidth > screenSize.width ?
            (imageWidth - screenSize.width) / 2
            : 0
            
            width = offset.width > 0 ?
                .minimum(widthLimit, offset.width) :
                .maximum(-widthLimit, offset.width)
        }
        
        let imageHeight = (scannedImage.size.height * originalScale) * newScale
        var height: CGFloat = .zero
        if imageHeight > screenSize.height {
            let heightLimit: CGFloat = imageHeight > screenSize.height ?
            (imageHeight - screenSize.height) / 2
            : 0
            
            height = offset.height > 0 ?
                .minimum(heightLimit, offset.height) :
                .maximum(-heightLimit, offset.height)
        }
        
        let newOffset = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        lastScale = newScale
        lastOffset = newOffset
        withAnimation() {
            offset = newOffset
            scale = newScale
        }
    }
```

This is how it's used on the image:

```
struct SignatureAddingView: View {
    
    @State var scannedImage: UIImage = UIImage()
    
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var scaleAnchor: UnitPoint = .center
    @State private var lastScale: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var lastOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var debug = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                
                let magnificationGesture = MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged{ gesture in
                        scaleAnchor = .center
                        scale = lastScale * gesture
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: geometry)
                    }
                
                let dragGesture = DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        var newOffset = lastOffset
                        newOffset.width += gesture.translation.width
                        newOffset.height += gesture.translation.height
                        offset = newOffset
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: geometry)
                    }
                
                Image(uiImage: scannedImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2,
                              y: geometry.size.height / 2)
                    .scaleEffect(scale, anchor: scaleAnchor)
                    .offset(offset)
                    .gesture(dragGesture)
                    .gesture(magnificationGesture)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            }

        }
         .background(Color.black.opacity(0.3))
         .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    } 

private func fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: GeometryProxy) {
// CODE IS HERE
}
}
```

How to implement Benzy Neez's solution to this part of code, so, for example, user can zoom into some part of the code and save the signature in small part of zoomed image?

Comment: Have a look at [ImageRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/imagerenderer)

Comment: It must be 14.0 +

Comment: Anyway an overlay is not part of the image, as the name implies it's a second layer. You need to capture the view (hierarchy) as image or you have to *`draw`* the signature onto the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is that you use a `GeometryReader` to deliver the frame of the part of the screen to be captured.

Here is a simple example using the screen capture technique which [kontiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7786555/kontiki) kindly provided as [an answer to another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57206207/20386264). Technically, the camera button is also inside the frame of the `GeometryReader`, because the `GeometryProxy` needs to be in scope for the tap callback. A y-offset has been applied to make it look like the button is outside the frame. Alternatively, you could keep the button in frame and hide it during the snapshot.

*EDIT* Updated to allow the signature to be dragged around, which makes the example more interesting!

*EDIT2* Updated to allow the main image to be scaled and moved too. More notes on this below the screenshot.

```swift
struct ScannedImage {
    let size: CGSize
}

struct ContentView: View {

    let scannedImage = ScannedImage(
        size: CGSize(width: 600, height: 380)
    )

    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var lastScale = CGFloat(1)
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var lastOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var minScalingFactor = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var maxScalingFactor = CGFloat.zero
    @State private var signatureOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var lastSignatureOffset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var snapshot: UIImage?

    private func determineInitialScaling(viewSize: CGSize) {

        // Start scaled-to-fill, allow scaling down to scaled-to-fit
        let imageRatio = scannedImage.size.width / scannedImage.size.height
        let geometryRatio = viewSize.width / viewSize.height
        if imageRatio > geometryRatio {
            scale = viewSize.height / scannedImage.size.height
            minScalingFactor = viewSize.width / scannedImage.size.width
        } else {
            scale = viewSize.width / scannedImage.size.width
            minScalingFactor = viewSize.height / scannedImage.size.height
        }
        lastScale = scale
        maxScalingFactor = scale * 3
    }

    private func correctOffsetIfNecessary(viewSize: CGSize) {

        // Determine the size of the scaled image
        let scaledWidth = max(scannedImage.size.width * scale, viewSize.width)
        let scaledHeight = max(scannedImage.size.height * scale, viewSize.height)

        // Determine the maximum offsets from the center
        let maxXOffset = (scaledWidth - viewSize.width) / 2
        let maxYOffset = (scaledHeight - viewSize.height) / 2

        // Correct the offset if necessary, to bring it back to the frame
        var correctedOffset = offset
        if abs(offset.width) > maxXOffset {
            correctedOffset.width = offset.width > 0 ? maxXOffset : -maxXOffset
        }
        if abs(offset.height) > maxYOffset {
            correctedOffset.height = offset.height > 0 ? maxYOffset : -maxYOffset
        }
        if correctedOffset != offset {
            withAnimation {
                offset = correctedOffset
            }
        }
        lastOffset = correctedOffset
    }

    private func magnificationGesture(geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some Gesture {
        MagnificationGesture()
            .onChanged{ gesture in
                scale = max(minScalingFactor, min(maxScalingFactor, lastScale * gesture))
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                lastScale = scale
                correctOffsetIfNecessary(viewSize: geometry.size)
            }
    }

    private func dragGesture(geometry: GeometryProxy) -> some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged { gesture in
                var newOffset = lastOffset
                newOffset.width += gesture.translation.width
                newOffset.height += gesture.translation.height
                offset = newOffset
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                correctOffsetIfNecessary(viewSize: geometry.size)
            }
    }

    private var mainImage: some View {
        Image(systemName: "fish.fill")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .padding(50)
            .foregroundColor(Color(red: 0.9, green: 0.45, blue: 0.0))
            .frame(width: scannedImage.size.width, height: scannedImage.size.height)
            .background(

                // The eye of the fish!
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(width: 80, height: 80)
                    .offset(x: 105, y: 5)
            )
            .background { Color(red: 0.47, green: 0.80, blue: 0.91) }
    }

    private var signature: some View {
        Image(systemName: "signature")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .foregroundColor(.black)
            .frame(height: 40)
            .padding()
            .background(.white.opacity(0.3))
            .shadow(color: .white, radius: 6)
            .padding()
            .offset(signatureOffset)
            .gesture(
                DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { value in
                        signatureOffset = CGSize(
                            width: lastSignatureOffset.width + value.translation.width,
                            height: lastSignatureOffset.height + value.translation.height
                        )
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        lastSignatureOffset = signatureOffset
                    }
            )
    }

    private var cameraButton: some View {
        Image(systemName: "camera.fill")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBackground))
            .padding(10)
            .frame(height: 50)
            .background(Color(UIColor.secondaryLabel))
            .cornerRadius(8)
            .accessibilityAddTraits(.isButton)
    }

    private func captureSnapshot(rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
        var result: UIImage?
        if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(
            where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
        ) as? UIWindowScene {
            result = scene.windows[0].rootViewController?.view.asImage(rect: rect)
        }
        return result
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private var framedSnapshot: some View {
        if let snapshot {
            Image(uiImage: snapshot)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
                .frame(width: 250)
                .padding(10)
                .border(.gray, width: 2)
                .background(.white)
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                    mainImage
                        .scaleEffect(scale)
                        .offset(offset)
                        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
                        .background(.white)
                        .clipped()
                        .gesture(dragGesture(geometry: geometry))
                        .gesture(magnificationGesture(geometry: geometry))
                        .onAppear {
                            determineInitialScaling(viewSize: geometry.size)
                        }
                        .overlay(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                            signature
                        }

                    cameraButton
                        .offset(y: 70)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            snapshot = captureSnapshot(rect: geometry.frame(in: .global))
                        }
                }
            }
            .frame(width: 350, height: 250)
            .padding(.bottom, 110)

            framedSnapshot

            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.top, 50)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color(UIColor.systemFill))
    }
}

// Credit to kontiki for the screenshot solution
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/57206207/20386264
extension UIView {
    func asImage(rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: rect)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Snapshot]

About scaling and moving the main image:

- You were applying `.scaledToFit` to the scanned image, before then scaling it again. This makes scaling more complicated, it is easier to scale directly from the default image size.
- The initial, minimum and maximum scaling factors are determined when the page is first shown in the `.onAppear` callback.
- The minimum and maximum scaling factors are enforced during magnification, so there is no need to "fix" these afterwards.
- However, if the image has moved away from the edges (either as a consequence of scaling or of moving) then this is fixed in `correctOffsetIfNecessary`, which is an updated implementation of your `fixOffsetAndScale`.
- I wasn't quite clear, why you were setting `.position` and using a `scaleAnchor` in your implementation, neither seemed necessary so I dropped these.
- Testing with a simulator is difficult (I couldn't get the hang of a two-finger gesture) but I tested on a physical iPhone 8 running iOS 16.6.1 and the snapshot works for me.

Comment: Thank you! I'm gonna test this solution after the weekend and write you about it)

Comment: It's a good solution, but I can't make it work with ```fixOffsetAndScale```. I've modified my question, so you would understand what I'm talking about.

Comment: OK, updated to allow the main image to be scaled and moved too. More notes on this can be found below the screenshot.

Comment: It's great, I'll keep this solution for now. One question: is it possible when we zoom into the image, in snapshot the image size stays unchanged, but signature is getting smaller?

Comment: Like we are positioning the signature by scaling the image at the back, and when we create a snapshot, the only thing is changing is signature.

Comment: The size of it, I mean

Comment: Pleased to hear it's closer to what you want, thanks for accepting the answer! I thought the signature was going to use the full-blown manipulation that you were asking about in [How to implement three gestures at the same time in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77052591/20386264). But if you want to apply the same scaling to the signature as for the main image then you probably need another state variable such as ```signatureScaleFactor``` that starts at 1.0 and gets updated at the same time as ```scale``` in the gesture callback. Then apply the modifier ```.scaleEffect``` to the overlay.

Comment: Thank you, I'll be trying to do that))) If I'll encounter problems with that - I'll create a new question and write to you) Thank you again!)))