# Zooming image and saving a signature ruins image display

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, snapshot

I am developing an iOS application that allows users to add a signature to an image and save it locally. Currently, when I use the captureSnapshot function while zoomed into the image, [it clips the image](https://imgur.com/a/PAGWGe4), which is not the intended behavior. I am seeking assistance in modifying the captureSnapshot function to achieve the following logic:

1. Zoom into the image.
2. Capture a snapshot of the zoomed-in portion with the signature.
3. Ensure that the signature appears correctly in the snapshot.
4. Zoom back out, and the signature remains visible, while the image remains unchanged.

I have included the code snippet below, which is a prototype of the captureSnapshot function, created with the help of [Benzy Neez](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77036269/how-to-save-image-with-positioned-signature-in-swiftui):

```swift
// Position of image
    @State private var scale: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var scaleAnchor: UnitPoint = .center
    @State private var lastScale: CGFloat = 1
    @State private var offset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var lastOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @State private var debug = ""
// Position of signature
    @State private var location: CGPoint = CGPoint(x: 150, y: 300)
    @GestureState private var fingerLocation: CGPoint? = nil
    @GestureState private var startLocation: CGPoint? = nil

//.......

// Main part that captures the snapshot
private func captureSnapshot(rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
    var result: UIImage?
    if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(
        where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
    ) as? UIWindowScene {
        result = scene.windows[0].rootViewController?.view.asImage(rect: rect)
    }
    return result
}

extension UIView {
    func asImage(rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: rect)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

```swift
// Image view itself
        VStack {
    
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        
        // This is my gestures, that I'm using on the image
        let magnificationGesture = MagnificationGesture()
            .onChanged{ gesture in
                scaleAnchor = .center
                scale = lastScale * gesture
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: geometry)
            }
        
        let dragGesture = DragGesture()
            .onChanged { gesture in
                var newOffset = lastOffset
                newOffset.width += gesture.translation.width
                newOffset.height += gesture.translation.height
                offset = newOffset
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: geometry)
            }
        // Image itself
        Image(uiImage: scannedImage)
            .resizable()
        //                    .scaledToFit()
            .border(.red, width: 2)
            .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2,
                      y: geometry.size.height / 2)
            .scaleEffect(scale, anchor: scaleAnchor)
            .offset(offset)
            .gesture(dragGesture)
            .gesture(magnificationGesture)
            .overlay (
                
                // Here in overlay we have our signature, I've removed all unnecessary parts
                VStack {
                    ZStack {
                        ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                            
                            Rectangle()
                                .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, dash: [5]))
                                .fill(.blue)
                                .opacity(opacity)
                            
                            Rectangle()
                                .fill(.clear)
                            
                            Image(uiImage: signImage)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                            
                            VStack {
                                HStack {
                                    Spacer()
                                    Circle()
                                        .fill(Color.green)
                                        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                        .onTapGesture {
                                            
                                            opacity = 0.0
                                            //                                                    scale = 1.0
                                            
                                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3, execute: {
                                                
                                                // This part is saving the snapshot                                                       scannedImage = captureSnapshot(rect: geometry.frame(in: .global))!
                                                
                                                opacity = 1.0
                                            })
                                        }
                                }
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            .opacity(opacity)
                            .zIndex(2)
                            
                            
                            
                        }
                        .frame(width: width, height: height)
                        
                    }
                    
                }
                    .frame(maxWidth: width, maxHeight: height, alignment: .center)
                    .position(location)
                    .gesture(
                        simpleDrag.simultaneously(with: fingerDrag)
                    )
            )
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
    }
    
    Spacer()
    
}
```

```
// This func is responsible on resizing the scannedImage    
private func fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: GeometryProxy) {
        let newScale: CGFloat = .minimum(.maximum(scale, 1), 4)
        let screenSize = geometry.size

        let originalScale = scannedImage.size.width / scannedImage.size.height >= screenSize.width / screenSize.height ?
        geometry.size.width / scannedImage.size.width :
        geometry.size.height / scannedImage.size.height

        let imageWidth = (scannedImage.size.width * originalScale) * newScale

        var width: CGFloat = .zero
        if imageWidth > screenSize.width {
            let widthLimit: CGFloat = imageWidth > screenSize.width ?
            (imageWidth - screenSize.width) / 2
            : 0

            width = offset.width > 0 ?
                .minimum(widthLimit, offset.width) :
                .maximum(-widthLimit, offset.width)
        }

        let imageHeight = (scannedImage.size.height * originalScale) * newScale
        var height: CGFloat = .zero
        if imageHeight > screenSize.height {
            let heightLimit: CGFloat = imageHeight > screenSize.height ?
            (imageHeight - screenSize.height) / 2
            : 0

            height = offset.height > 0 ?
                .minimum(heightLimit, offset.height) :
                .maximum(-heightLimit, offset.height)
        }

        let newOffset = CGSize(width: width, height: height)
        lastScale = newScale
        lastOffset = newOffset
        withAnimation() {
            offset = newOffset
            scale = newScale
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scaling and fitting a signature image within a VStack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77057542/scaling-and-fitting-a-signature-image-within-a-vstack)

Comment: Unfortunately, this code is incomplete, so the only person who is going to be able to try out changes is you. It is also difficult to examine because the nesting is so deep. So to get to the bottom of the problem, I would suggest you try to break up the body into its component parts. The example that you linked to shows how this can be done. Then look very carefully at the order and places in which the modifiers are being applied. In particular, try comparing the way that the example applies frames and scaling and the way it is being done here, because it's not the same. That may be the cause.