# Weird reaction of the image on snapshot creation (SwiftUI)

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, snapshot

I'm working on an iOS app, and I have a problem with the scannedImage in my SwiftUI view. I'm using [kontiki's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57200521/how-to-convert-a-view-not-uiview-to-an-image/57206207#57206207) to capture a snapshot of the view, and it works fine. Here's the screen of [how does it look like](https://imgur.com/a/JDSjR70). However, after the snapshot is taken, the scannedImage changes its frame size, it's resizing [to the bottom of the view](https://imgur.com/a/gfqbLay), and this behavior only happens once. Also it's only happening at the bottom, as you can see in the second link, it's successfully cropping it if I'm positing my signature on left and right places and pressing green. I'm not sure why this is happening, I've tried to catch the time when scannedImage size is changing, but no luck. Hope you can help with it. Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
// Main part that capturing the snapshot
private func captureSnapshot(rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
    var result: UIImage?
    if let scene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first(
        where: { $0.activationState == .foregroundActive }
    ) as? UIWindowScene {
        result = scene.windows[0].rootViewController?.view.asImage(rect: rect)
    }
    return result
}

extension UIView {
    func asImage(rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: rect)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

```
// View itself 
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            GeometryReader { geometry in

                let magnificationGesture = MagnificationGesture()
                    .onChanged{ gesture in
                        scaleAnchor = .center
                        scale = lastScale * gesture
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: geometry)
                    }
                
                let dragGesture = DragGesture()
                    .onChanged { gesture in
                        var newOffset = lastOffset
                        newOffset.width += gesture.translation.width
                        newOffset.height += gesture.translation.height
                        offset = newOffset
                    }
                    .onEnded { _ in
                        fixOffsetAndScale(geometry: geometry)
                    }
                                    
                Image(uiImage: scannedImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .border(.gray, width: 2)
                    .scaleEffect(scale, anchor: scaleAnchor)
                    .offset(offset)
                    .gesture(dragGesture)
                    .gesture(magnificationGesture)
                    .overlay (
                        VStack {
                            ZStack {
                                ZStack(alignment: .bottomTrailing) {
                                    
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 2, dash: [5]))
                                        .fill(.blue)
                                        .opacity(opacity)
                                    
                                    Rectangle()
                                        .fill(.clear)
                                    
                                    Image(uiImage: signImage)
                                        .resizable()
                                        .scaledToFit()
                                    
                                    VStack {
                                        HStack {
                                            Spacer()
                                            Circle()
                                                .fill(Color.green)
                                                .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                                                .onTapGesture {
                                                    
                                                    opacity = 0.0
                                                    
                                                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3, execute: {
                                                        
                                                        scannedImage = captureSnapshot(rect: geometry.frame(in: .global))!
                                                                                                                
                                                        opacity = 1.0
                                                    })
                                                }
                                        }
                                        Spacer()
                                    }
                                    .opacity(opacity)
                                    .zIndex(2)

                                }
                                .frame(width: width, height: height)
                                
                            }
                            
                        }
                            .frame(maxWidth: width, maxHeight: height, alignment: .center)
                            .position(location)
                            .gesture(
                                simpleDrag.simultaneously(with: fingerDrag)
                            )
                    )
                
                Spacer()
//                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            }
            
        }
        .onChange(of: scannedImage.size.height, perform: { newValue in
            print("height changed, but why?!")
        })
        .background(Color.black.opacity(0.3).ignoresSafeArea(.all))

    }
```

My guess is that the problem is with `captureSnapshot`, It's getting more, then It's supposed to. Hope you can help with it, thank you.

EDIT: The `Spacer()` is not the problem.

Comment: You are displaying ```scannedImage``` inside a GeometryReader and using the frame of the ```GeometryReader``` to capture a snapshot. This snapshot is then used to replace the ```scannedImage```. But the frame of the ```GeometryReader``` also includes a ```Spacer```. Try moving the ```Spacer``` outside the ```GeometryReader```.

Comment: No, unfortunately the problem is not in the Spacer(). Even If I remove it from the code, the problem does not leave.

Comment: Oh, didn't catch you nickname, hello again)

Comment: The image is being ```scaledToFit``` and you are also applying a ```scaleFactor``` to it. But the snapshot is of the scaled image. So I would not even expect it to be the same size. It will only stay the same size if it exactly fits the frame to start with and if you do not apply any more scaling (that is, if ```scale``` is set to 1).

Comment: This is helping! If I'm removing the ```.scaledToFit```, the image is appearing at the bottom of the view and unknown free space isn't appearing! You have my gratitude) P.s. I hope you're not getting tired answering my questions here, we're speaking like 4 days now)))

Comment: In that case I'll make it an answer and you can show your gratitude by accepting it! Thx.

Comment: Will be waiting for it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two likely reasons why `scannedImage` is changing size:

1. You are displaying `scannedImage` inside a `GeometryReader` and using the frame of the `GeometryReader` to capture a snapshot. This snapshot is then used to replace the `scannedImage`. But the frame of the `GeometryReader` also includes a `Spacer`. Try moving the `Spacer` to outside the `GeometryReader`.
2. The image is being `scaledToFit` and you are also applying a `scaleFactor` to it. But the snapshot is of the scaled image. So I would not even expect it to be the same size. It will only stay the same size if it exactly fits the frame to start with and if you do not apply any more scaling (that is, if `scale` is set to 1).