# Render a XAML page to an image

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to render a Xamarin Forms XAML page as an image, when running inside my app.

Is this possible?

I am aware that I can use native platform APIs to capture the screen, however I want to capture all information, including any information outside of the bottom boundary of the screen.

**To clarify on the comments...**

I'm not after a screenshot. I need to be able to save the contents of the view/page (including where the user would need to scroll) into an image.

Comment: This should use dependencyservice in each platform . https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-forms-capture-screenshot-using-dependencyservice2/

Comment: Umm like a screenshot? I mean I am not sure what you are asking for!

Comment: Based on your clarification, you need a scrollshot?

Comment: If so, for Android, check this out: https://programmingcode4life.blogspot.com/2016/10/convert-layout-view-to-image-and-store.html - for iOS, you could use this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696307/how-to-convert-a-uiview-to-an-image but make sure instead of UIView you use UIScrollView