# Create tintable image with solid colour, so that it can adapt Dark and Light modes

Tags: swift, ios-darkmode

I need to create UIImage (bitmap?) filled with a solid colour so that it can be tinted and thus support Dark and Light mode changes
Is there a way to do this in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way, but a quick and dirty way to do this would be make a UIView with a background the color you want and then use one of the many ways to go UIView -> UIImage.
This stack overflow question here does exactly that:
[How to convert a UIView to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696307/how-to-convert-a-uiview-to-an-image/30696627)
Furthermore, looking at that code will give you some insights on how to do it the right way, with lower level graphics functions if you like.