# Attempting to use UIGraphicsImageRenderer with a SCNView produces empty results

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I'm trying to take a screenshot of a SCNView to display elsewhere. Since SCNView inherits from UIView, I thought I could [use a `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41288197/35690):

```
extension UIView {

    // Using a function since `var image` might conflict with an existing variable
    // (like on `UIImageView`)
    func asImage() -> UIImage {
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(bounds: bounds)
        return renderer.image { rendererContext in
            layer.render(in: rendererContext.cgContext)
        }
    }
}
```

When I attempt to use this code on an SCNView, it causes a blank (white) UIImage (of the correct bounds).

How do I take a screenshot of a SCNView correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a UIGraphicsImageRenderer to get a screenshot, just call the [snapshot](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnview/1524031-snapshot) method on SCNView:

```
let image = sceneView.snapshot()
```