# How to add some text under the image using UIKit

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uiimage, core-graphics

I have an image like this:

[image: first]

But I want to add some text **under** this image and get it like a new UIImage, for example:

[image: second]

As I understand I should create a new image. Then put my image into it and add a text.
How can I do it?

I tried to use something like this, but couldn't place my text under the image

```
func textToImage(drawText text: String, inImage image: UIImage, atPoint point: CGPoint) -> UIImage {
    let textColor = UIColor.white
    let textFont = UIFont(name: "Helvetica Bold", size: 12)!

    let scale = UIScreen.main.scale
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(image.size, false, scale)

    let textFontAttributes = [
        NSAttributedStringKey.font: textFont,
        NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: textColor,
        ] as [NSAttributedStringKey : Any]
    image.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: image.size))

    let rect = CGRect(origin: point, size: image.size)
    text.draw(in: rect, withAttributes: textFontAttributes)

    let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```

PS Background of my image is clear. Red is a background of another view.

Comment: SwiftUI or UIKit?

Comment: Sorry, I use UIKit

Comment: You surely tried _something_. SO is not a free code writing website. Without showing at least some (research) effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: I added my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you should always show some code of what you have attempted so far. But this is a kind of trivial view that should looks something similar to:

```
class ViewWithImage: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setup()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    fatalError("storyboards no thanks")
}

private func setup() {
    backgroundColor = .red
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "garbagecan")
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    imageView.tintColor = .white
    
    let deleteLabel = UILabel()
    deleteLabel.text = "Delete"
    deleteLabel.textColor = .white
    
    let vStack = UIStackView()
    vStack.axis = .vertical
    vStack.spacing = 8
    addSubview(vStack)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        vStack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
        vStack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        vStack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -16),
        vStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 16)
    ])
    
    vStack.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
    vStack.addArrangedSubview(deleteLabel)
}
```

}

Comment: Thx, I added my code. I should get it like a new UIImage

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33644345/4757272

Comment: Thx, it looks good. But maybe there is any way to do it without UIView?

Comment: Yes, but it's more complex and no need to complicate things.