# Can i set a Custom UIFont to italic in an UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I have to use SpaceGrotesk google font but does not have an italic style. This is the font https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Space+Grotesk . So my question is can i add it to an UILabel and change it to italic? Any help appreciated. Currently i am using it like this...

```
   UIFont* nameLabelFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"SpaceGrotesk-Bold" size:20];
    self.nameLabel.font = nameLabelFont;
```

**UPDATE**

**

```
I used the following command from 2D graphics API and it actually works. 


   CGAffineTransform transfromFontToItalic = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, tanf(15 * (CGFloat)M_PI / 180), 1, 0, 0);
 UIFontDescriptor * fontItalic = [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithName:@"SpaceGrotesk-Regular" matrix:transformFontToItalic]; 
self.usernameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontD size:10];
```

**

Comment: You can't really. Maybe by redrawing each character with a low level code, but there is no possibility currently. No "fake italic" option.

Comment: Really not even with fontWithDescriptor?  UIFontDescriptor * fontD = [usernameLabelFont.fontDescriptor
                fontDescriptorWithSymbolicTraits:UIFontDescriptorTraitItalic];
    self.usernameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontD size:5];

Comment: With font descriptor, it will try to fetch one corresponding to the descriptors, but won't create a new font... Or at least that what's it should be doing in theory. Did you try to see?

Comment: oh ok i thought it can do it. Because in android it works like this. Yeah i tried actually does not work!

Comment: Open your font file with Font Book to see if it has the Italic typeface.  If it doesn't, you have no question to start with.

Comment: You can do it using 2D graphics command  CGAffineTransform matrix = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, tanf(15 * (CGFloat)M_PI / 180), 1, 0, 0);
    UIFontDescriptor * fontD = [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithName:@"SpaceGrotesk-Regular" matrix:matrix];
    self.usernameLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontD size:10];

Comment: DIdn't know about the matrix. Interesting information. If this really works, might want to answer your own question. But, it's indeed a "fake italic", and effect added manually (ans the angle could be anything).

Comment: Yeah it works correctly but its still fake, but looks like its not!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it's worth it, but here are the steps:

1. Convert the label into an image. See [How to convert a UIView to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696307/how-to-convert-a-uiview-to-an-image)
2. Crop the image to about 20 separate images, each one of them representing a separate horizontal line (height: 1, width: the original label width). See [Cropping an UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158914/cropping-an-uiimage)
3. Using code, place the separate images one below the other, with the trailing constraint decremented for each next line

Note: This solution assumes that the label is 1 line

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve the effect with help of `UIFont`'s class method -

```
+ (UIFont *)fontWithDescriptor:(UIFontDescriptor *)descriptor size:(CGFloat)pointSize
```

and `UIKit`'s UIFontDescriptor method as mentioned below

```
+ (UIFontDescriptor *)fontDescriptorWithName:(NSString *)fontName matrix:(CGAffineTransform)matrix
```

In the above FontDescriptor method change the value of **C** `0 < C < 1` to have the inclination (check `CGAffineTransform` syntax below)

**NB** - Syntax of `CGAffineTransform` is like this - `CGAffineTransformMake(CGFloat a, CGFloat b, CGFloat c, CGFloat d, CGFloat tx, CGFloat ty)`

**Code:**

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0);
UIFontDescriptor * fontDesc = [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithName:@"SpaceGrotesk-Regular" matrix:transform];
self.lblUsername.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontDesc size:20];
self.lblUsername.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.5 alpha:0.5];
self.lblUsername.text = @"A quick brown fox, jumps over the lazy dog";
```