# UIGraphicsImageRenderer and UIGraphicsBeginImageContext: What is useful for UIImage.draw(in: CGRect)

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, uiimage, uigraphicsimagerenderer

I am newbie in swift and wanted to use UIImage.draw(in: CGRect) in my application to resize image. When I used UIGraphicsImageRenderer, it made some memory spikes rather than using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext. Since Apple [discourages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41288197/19574539) using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext in spite of UIGraphicsImageRenderer, how can I remove the memory spikes?

Comment: Please review [ask]. You need to provide example code showing what you are doing, as well as explaining how you are profiling it to determine "memory spikes."