# swift How to change uiimage background and selected area color

Tags: swift, uiimage

i have a uiimage like this white background and selected area color (red),

i want to save as this image ,

become black background and selected area color become to white,

how can to it ?

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should elaborate a bit. How are you creating the red selection line? My guess is the reds are UIViews and the image is a UIImageView. Put them inside a parent UIView and take snapshot of that parent UIView. Follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30696307/how-to-convert-a-uiview-to-an-image) for converting UIView to image.